# HTTP 400 when requesting disk

Tags: python, google-compute-engine

I'm using the python API launch some instances on GCE and I'm hitting some problems when creating the instance. I'm trying to attach a persistent disk to my instance however when I try to create the instance it gives me the following error:

```
HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1beta16/projects/projectid/zones/us-central1-a/instances?alt=json returned "Invalid value for field 'resource.disks[0].source': 'https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/projectid/zones/us-central1-a/disks/hm'.  Must be a URL to a Compute resource in the same zone."
```

And the JSON for the disk is:

```
"disks": [
            {
              "kind": "compute#attachedDisk",
              "boot": "true",
              "type": "PERSISTENT",
              "mode": "READ_WRITE",
              "deviceName": "%s" % instance_name,
              "zone": "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/projectid/zones/us-central1-a/",
              "source": "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/projectid/zones/us-central1-a/disks/%s" % instance_name,
            }
          ]
```

Where the variable 'instance_name' is being put in by python.

I'm not sure why this is happening as the disk exists and it is in the same zone.

Any one have any suggestions?

Thanks,

George

** UPDATE **

I solved the issue by updating to the v1 API

Comment: It looks like there may be a missing replacement for "projectid"?

Comment: Sorry, should have said that I replaced the actual project id with "projectid" for this example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by updating to the v1 API

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are trying to attach a persistent disk in one region (us_central1-a) to an instance in a different zones. Persistent disks are per zone, you cannot attach to instances across zones, only disk snapshots are accessible across zones.

The very last part of the error message you are getting indicates this:

> HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1beta16/projects/projectid/zones/us-central1-a/instances?alt=json returned "Invalid value for field 'resource.disks[0].source': 'https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/projectid/zones/us-central1-a/disks/hm'.  **Must be a URL to a Compute resource in the same zone."**

Your disk is in **us-central1-a**, which zone are you trying to create your instance in?

If you want to use that disk in a different zone, such as **europe-west1-a** then you will either have to:

1) Create a temporary instance in the same zone, attaching the disk, then use the **gcutil moveinstances** command to move the instance to the required zone. This will move the disk with it, you can then detach the disk from that instance in the new zone and use it.

OR

2) Create a snapshot of the disk, and then use that to create your instances persistent disk:

1. Create a snapshot (snapshot1) of your persistent disk (hm) in us-central1-a:

   gcutil addsnapshot snapshot1 --zone us-central1-a --source_disk hm
2. Create a new persistent disk (disk2) from that snapshot (snapshot1) in the required region:

   gcutil adddisk "disk2" --zone="europe-west1-a" --source_snapshot="snapshot1"
3. Create your new instance (instance2) using the new persistent disk (disk2):

   gcutil addinstance "instance2" --zone="europe-west1-a" --disk="disk2,deviceName=disk2,mode=READ_WRITE,boot"

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I did state in my question that both the resources are in the same zone. I should have posted that I solved the problem by updating the API version I was using.